# Click() not firing from <a href> when link is clicked

Tags: jquery, click

Just wondering what the issue is with click() firing from an a href.

Code snippet below, thanks ahead of time guys.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // (4n+4) selects every 4th p starting at 4 onward
   $('<a href="#top" class="bac">back to top</a>').insertAfter('div.chapter p:nth-child(4n+4)');
   $('a id="top">,/a>').prependTo('body');

   $('.bac').click(function() {
       alert("Testing");
   });
});
```

Comment: use event delegation use `.on()` for dynamically added elements

Comment: I tried using on(click, function() but had the same results where it fires the to top, but never the alert

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: where is your html. i has been test, it run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `'a id="top">,/a>'` in the following line would result in an error, because jQuery doesn't know what to do with it (it's not valid HTML and not a valid selector):

```
$('a id="top">,/a>').prependTo('body');
```

So then the code after that with the `.click()` binding would not be reached.

Fix the HTML in that string to create an anchor:

```
$('<a id="top"></a>').prependTo('body');
```

Comment: ty! that was it, no clue when that got wonky on me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `preventDefault` 
 - https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

```
$(".bac").click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("Testing");
});
```

Comment: Not sure that would work since I want both things to fire.

Comment: see if you can at least get the alert with my example, then we go from there

Comment: yeah, no luck, attached it to something else to see if it worked then and it's fine, just not on the a href

Answer (score 0):

Think this would work

$('#top').prependTo('body');